# List item in jQuery Mobile navbar smaller than others

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

So I'm trying to add a navbar to the footer of my pages in jQuery Mobile, with three list items. The first and last are data icons, while the one in the middle is simple text. The problem is that the middle item (Contact Us) is shorter than the other two, and I can't figure out a way to get them to all be equal sizes. Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1 style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">Title</h1>
  </div>


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="home"></a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w68z6ho1/). Thanks!

Comment: What screen size you are using for testing?

Comment: A bunch of different ones - they all have the same problem.

Comment: No this is not problem and having different output in different screen.

Comment: It isn't the width that is the problem, It's the height. "Contact Us" is shorter than the other two. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/w68z6ho1/3/

Comment: Height problem is just because of Icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added simple padding on contact us Hyperlink:

```
.contact-us{padding: 12px;}
```

Here is footer markup:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="home"></a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ypm7sxkL/)

> **Note:** This height issue is just because of Icon on Navbar taking
>   different height them text. Use custom css is pretty nice idea.

Comment: Super simple solution that works - I was thinking a bit too hard into it. Thanks!